# how to emit value to one angular specific component page to app component page

Tags: angular

I want to implement shopping card component page angular.
I have a app.component.page with this code

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class="col-md-6"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span >
        0 article
      </span></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><a routerLink="basket">basket</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class='row'>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my page product.comoponent, i have this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><a #mat1 [attr.data-pat]="lunel" (click)="getCategory(mat1.dataset.pat)">ProdA</a></tr>
        <tr><a #mat2 [attr.data-pat]="martins" (click)="getCategory(mat2.dataset.pat)">ProdB</a></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let prod of result.produit; let index=index"> 
            <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
            <td>{{prod.price}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add to basket</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to implement the basket component page with these conditions

- In the product component page when i click on the "Add to basket" , i must increment the value of article and seeing the result on the product component page. How can i do it, the 0 article value is in the app.component.html page
- In the basket component page how to list all the product selected by customer (in product component page) in the table tag and add a button to help the customer to remove a product and change the value of article or to increment number of article ?

this is my stackblitz link    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4er2hh

Any idea ?

Comment: This is what services are for really..

Comment: create a stackblitz and mock some data. that way it will be easy for us to help you

Comment: Hello @ionut-t this is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4er2hh